# Проблемы с системой Debian 9.5

Tags: debian

После попытки обновиться вместо пользователя root вижу bash. Так же ругается dpkg. Ещё вылазила ошибка в базе обновлений. apt install ничего не инсталирует. install - f не помогает.
Вот что я вижу при входе

```
-bash: .: /etc/bash.bashrc: cannot execute binary file
-bash-4.4# apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  base-files libapache2-mod-php7.2 libmariadbclient18
  libpng16-16 php7.2 php7.2-cli php7.2-common php7.2-curl
  php7.2-gd php7.2-json php7.2-mbstring php7.2-mysql
  php7.2-opcache php7.2-readline php7.2-sqlite3
  php7.2-sqlite3-dbgsym php7.2-xml
17 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/5558 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7168 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Видно где-то застрял бинарник. Как его убить?

А если продолжить апгрейд, то вот такие ошибки:

```
-bash: .: /etc/bash.bashrc: cannot execute binary file
-bash-4.4# apt upgrade -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  base-files libapache2-mod-php7.2 libmariadbclient18
  libpng16-16 php7.2 php7.2-cli php7.2-common php7.2-curl
  php7.2-gd php7.2-json php7.2-mbstring php7.2-mysql
  php7.2-opcache php7.2-readline php7.2-sqlite3
  php7.2-sqlite3-dbgsym php7.2-xml
17 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/5558 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7168 B of additional disk space will be used.
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
dpkg: error: corrupt info database format file '/var/lib/dpkg/info/format'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
-bash-4.4#
```

Как вернуть все в прежнее состояние? Ещё я подключал по мануалу репозиторий mono как у них на сайте.

Comment: О какой попытке обновиться речь?

Comment: Просто выполнить apt upgrade. Сыпятся ошибки. И странно, что пользователь мой перестал отображаться. Вместо него теперь bash 4.4. Хотя захожу я под рутом.

Comment: Я так и не понял, после какого действия на сервере всё сломалось? Или само по себе, что ли?

Comment: мне кажется чёто с apt? попробуйте зайти под root`ом через Е во время загрузки, и установить apt-utils как просит эта ошибка debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed

Comment: @Dmitriy не получится установить, потому что corrupt info database format file. Неужели вас больше ничего не смущает?

Comment: @andreymal да всё, уже весь засмущался =) вот как исправить corrupt info database format file. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329983/dpkg-format-file-is-corrupt/329991#329991 , просто удаляем его и делаем новый

Comment: Думаю после попытки поставить mono-develop. Я выполнил действия как у них на сайте для Ubuntu 18.04. (на пк так работало) и сделал update, upgrade. До конца он так и не установил. Вылез bash. Ребутнул сервер - не помогло. Вообще были неполадки на хостинге (восстанавливал резервную копию), но все вроде работало. А теперь и восстановление не помогает.

Comment: @Dmitriy а теперь почитайте первый комментарий к тому ответу — очень очень большая вероятность, что здесь у автора вопроса будет то же самое.

Comment: @andreymal ну мы же не пробывали

Comment: @andreymal да Вы наверно правы, sudo то у него врятли работает

Comment: @Dmitriy у автора сломан грёбаный bash! Надо сперва понять, что за апокалипсис случился, что сломался аж bash, а уже потом с файлами dpkg разбираться

Comment: @ANTARES о каких неполадках на хостинге речь?

Comment: Вот только это хостинг. VPS. Там нет такой возможности. А просто установить могу попробовать.

Comment: А, я пробовал удалять. Ни к чему это не привело

Comment: Не сказали. Была речь о повреждении файлов. На Джино всегда что-то происходит. Но ведь работало.

Comment: @ANTARES может оказаться так, что эти повреждённые файлы проще всего починить полной переустановкой сервера

Comment: @ANTARES и да, если «всегда что-то происходит», то с такого хостинга нужно срочно валить на что-то более стабильное

Comment: @andreymal видимо придётся заново разворачивать.

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` потом `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

Похоже `/etc/bash.bashrc` поврежден. Соответственно не установилась переменная `PATH`. Поэтому `dpkg` не исполняется.

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

apt-get -f install
```

Обычно помогает.

Проверьте файлы:

- /etc/bash.bashrc
- /etc/profile
- /etc/profile.d/*